# Querying a mysql json array against another array in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to query a mysql database. I need to only return the values that are present in an outside array:

```
query_data = tours.select(:orders)

=> [#<Tour:0x007fd1b0972438 orders: [223597]>, ...]
```

I have an outside array that looks like this: `orders = [223597, 223598]`

Right now, I am using ruby to filter the data, but it isn't as efficient as I would like:

```
query_data = query_data.find_all do |data|
  data.orders.any? { |o| orders.include?(o) }
end
```

So my question is, how can I check the database array against the orders array and only return the records with those ID's present in the database array, using only SQL?

I was attempting something like this, but I don't think it was the right way to do it:

```
query_data.where("JSON_EXTRACT('tour.orders', '$[*]') IN #{orders}")
```

Plus, it just straight doesn't work.

Versions:

```
Ruby: 2.3.1
mysql: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Rails: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JSON_EXTRACT()` in the WHERE clause of an SQL query guarantees it will not be able to use an index. So it's going to do a table-scan, which is not more efficient.

In general, I recommend to developers who have a JSON column in their database:

You can extract part of a JSON document in the SELECT-list:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(tour.orders, '..expr..') FROM ...
```

But don't do that in any other clause of your SQL query. Not in the WHERE clause, nor in a JOIN expression, or in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, HAVING, etc. There are many cases that can't be optimized, and it makes your SQL queries super complicated, hard to code, hard to read, and hard to maintain.

Instead, if you want to compare against individual elements of a JSON array, you should store them in a normalized manner, one item per row in a child table.

For example, you might have a table `tour_orders` where each row has a reference to the `tour.id` and one order id. Then you can query it in a more readable way:

```
query_data.where(order: orders)
```

Using the JSON data type in MySQL makes it easy to insert lots of data, but makes many types of queries much harder. I recommend to avoid the JSON data type if you need SQL expressions to access individual elements of a JSON document.

Comment: Yeah...I wish I was in a position to rework the db. Might have to stick with the ruby solution for the time being.